# Pandas - Replace other columns in row with 0 if a specific column has a value of 1

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example dataframe:

```
X Y Z 
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
```

Now, here is the rule I've come up with:

- X is left as is
- If Y is equal to 1 set the corresponding value in X to 0
- If Z is equal to 1 set the corresponding value in X and Y to 0

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
X Y Z 
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

My first thought at a solution is this:

```
df_null_list = ['X']

for i in ['Y', 'Z']:

    df[df[i] == 1][df_null_list] = 0

    df_null_list.append(i)
```

When I do this and sum across the y axis, i'm starting to get values of 2 and 4 which don't make sense. Note, i'm referring to when I ran this on the actual dataset.

Do you have any suggestions for improvements or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df['X'] = df['X'].mask(df.Y == 1, 0)
df[['X', 'Y']] = df[['X', 'Y']].mask(df.Z == 1, 0)
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.Y == 1, 'X'] = 0
df.loc[df.Z == 1, ['X', 'Y']] = 0

print (df)
   X  Y  Z
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize this to wanting the last index of `1` per row to remain `1`, and leave everything else as `0`.  For performance operate on the underlying `numpy` array:

```
a = df.values
idx = (a.shape[1] - a[:, ::-1].argmax(1)) - 1
t = np.zeros(a.shape)
t[np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx] = 1
```

```
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

---

If you need the result back as a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(t, columns=df.columns, index=df.index).astype(int)
```

```
   X  Y  Z
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to perform an expanding operation on the rows axis using `numpy`:

```
df1 = df.copy() == 1
df1.iloc[:,::-1].expanding(axis=1).apply(
                 lambda x: x[-1] * np.prod(np.logical_not(x[:-1]))
                 ).iloc[:,::-1]

     X    Y    Z
0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
```